# How to start with CKFinder in MVC4 asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ckfinder

I want to use trial Library of Ck-finder in my asp.net mvc4 application. i am not getting exact clue .please help me with some links and examples.

Any Kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want to archive exactly and where you are stuck with?

Comment: I done with Integrate of ck finder with ck editor but i want to open ck finder only how to do?

Comment: Sorry without any code you've tried or any setup it's not clear or possible to help you.

Comment: http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the instructions](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Installation) I followed to get my instance of CK Finder working:

1. Copy the distribution files to your web server and place them in the `/ckfinder/` folder (or any other folder of your website).
2. Create a new folder on the server that will be used to store all uploaded files. By default, CKFinder is configured to use the `/ckfinder/userfiles/` folder of your website.
3. Make the user files folder writable for the Internet user. On Windows systems, give write permissions to the IUSR_ user.
4. Edit the config.ascx file. Make sure you have correctly set all settings in that file, and that you have enabled CKFinder. See Configuration for more information.
5. Create a reference to the `CKFinder.dll` file in your project by using one of the methods described below:

   - manually copy the `CKFinder.dll` file (it is located in the `ckfinder/bin/Release` directory) to the bin directory of your website,
   - or in your Visual Studio.NET project, right-click References in the Solution Explorer section, use Browse to select the `CKFinder.dll` file from the directory you have saved it in.

You should be ready to go. Open the `_samples/aspx/standalone.aspx` page in your browser to test and see CKFinder in action.

**Security Tips**

While installing and configuring CKFinder, keep the following important issues in mind.

- In IIS, you may set Execute Permissions to "none" in the properties of the user files folder (the folder created in step 2 above).
- The config.ascx file contains many important security settings. Make sure you have reviewed and understood all of them.
- Implement a full authentication solution in the `CheckAuthentication()` function, for example based on session variables. Do not simply "return true" from it as it will make it possible for any user (including anonymous users) to upload and delete files on your server.